# Android Studio Possible Data Binding Error

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-databinding

[Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IidQs.png)

[XML Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bx6vV.png)

I keep getting these errors when I try to implement data binding in my project, not sure what is causing it . I've checked all my xml classes and the are pointing to the appropriate viewModel. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: please share error log here or your layout so I can help you.

Comment: ok I have attached the image titled xml layout

Answer (score 0):

According to java convention, Package names should be written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the names of classes. And it creates problem in Data Binding. So change all your package names to lower case.